# Data not populating in react DataTable

Tags: reactjs

Im pretty new to ReactJS and Im trying to do an array map to a data table output. Im using graphql and aws amplify.

This is my app.js

```
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Posts from './Posts';


function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);


  // function to get all post data
  async function fetchPosts() {
    try {
      const postData = await API.graphql({ query: listPosts });
      let postsArray = postData.data.listPosts.items;
      console.log(postsArray)
      setPostState(postsArray);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err })
    }
  }

  async function setPostState(postsArray) {
    setPosts(postsArray)
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      
      <Posts posts={posts} />
      
    </div>

  );
}


export default App;
```

And this is my post.js code

```
import React from 'react'
import { css } from '@emotion/css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables"
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
import $ from 'jquery'; 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});


export default function Posts({
  posts = [],

  
}) {
  return (
      
    <>
      

    <table id="example" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Text id</th>
                <th>Analysed Text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                posts.map(post => (
                    <tr key ={post}>
                        <td>{post.id}</td>
                        <td>{post.description}</td>
                    </tr>

                ))
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
            
    </>
  )
}
```

For some reason the data is not populating to the datatable. I have tried to check if i can populate static data to the data table and it can be done. As such, I suspect it has something to do with the map function. I have also checked that there is data in my posts array as I have done a console log and the data is there.

PS: It seems that it picked up the empty array first and only after that the data is populated.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. The first render is supposed to be empty so there is no concern there. The second one looks good. What I suspect is happening is your JQuery is creating an empty datatable on first render by `$('#example').DataTable()`. So can you comment out that code and try again and see if the data actually appears? That way we know which tree to bark up.

Comment: Hi code Monkey, yes it appeared. But i need the $('#example').DataTable() because it will render my datatable as the datatable library comes with the search and pagniation feature. If not it will just render a normal table.

Comment: I think i got it. I moved the import $ from 'jquery';  into my async fetchPosts function because I figured the JS must be loading before the asynchornous call for the data. not sure if this is the best way though

Comment: Keep in mind that using JQuery in your JSX files is, if I may be so bold, sheer folly. Frankly, if you find yourself having to use JQuery along with react, you're probably doing something wrong. As for data tables, this is what you should be using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component